# Writing Arabic text annotation in pdf

Tags: java, angular, acrobat

I have a problem to update a pdf file with arabic text annotation

the pdf has been changed ( size has been changed)

and when I try to open the pdf with acrobat reader the text annotation is not displayed

and when I try to change the fill color of the annotation it has been displayed

[image]

I use this code in angular

```
 const blob = new Blob([content], { type: "application/pdf ; charset=utf-8" });
              const reader = new FileReader();          
              reader.readAsDataURL(blob); this.formData.append('files', blob,fileName);
```

and I use this java code to update the pdf file

```
public String storeFile(MultipartFile file) {
        // Normalize file name
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());

        try {
            // Check if the file's name contains invalid characters
            if(fileName.contains("..")) {
                throw new FileStorageException("Sorry! Filename contains invalid path sequence " + fileName);
            }

            // Copy file to the target location (Replacing existing file with the same name)
            Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
            //add owners permission
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
            perms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);

            Path targetLocation = this.fileStorageLocation.resolve(fileName);

            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), targetLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

            return fileName;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new FileStorageException("Could not store file " + fileName + ". Please try again!", ex);
        }
    }
```